# Maximizing Sparsity in l1 Minimization?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, na.numerical-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Consider the optimization problem

$$\min_x ||Ax||_1 + \lambda||x-b||^2,$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $x,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda$ is strictly greater than 0. (This problem is closely related to the "lasso" problem in basis pursuit.)  Can anything be said about the value of $\lambda$ for which $Ax^*$ is sparsest?  Clearly some values are bad: for instance, if $\lambda$ is huge and $b$ is dense then it is unlikely that $Ax^\star$ will be very sparse.

In other words: among all $\lambda > 0$ there is at least one value $\lambda^\star$ such that $||Ax^\star(\lambda)||_0$ is minimized.  Are there, say, bounds on $\lambda^\star$ in terms of $A$ and $b$?  I'd also be interested in results pertaining to basis pursuit or other similar problems.

*Edit:* I'm primarily interested in problems where ideal sparsity cannot be achieved, i.e., $||Ax^\star(\lambda^\star)||_0 > 0.$  (Assume that $A$ is square w/ full rank and $b \ne 0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate sparseness occurs when $Ax^*(\lambda)=0$, which is the case when the minimizer $x^*$ is the projection of $b$ onto $\ker A$. For this to happen, $\lambda$ must be small enough so that the restriction of $A$ to the orthogonal complement of its kernel is bounded from below by a constant greater than $2\lambda \mathrm{dist}(b,\ker A)$. Here the lower bound for operator is understood in the $\ell^2\to\ell^1$ norm.

Comment: Thanks for your response; what you say is true. I should have mentioned that I'm interested in the case where A has full rank, hence Ax*=0 only when x*=0, which corresponds to lambda=0 (or b=0).

Comment: Ah, I see.  It didn't occur to me that the l2->l1 norm bounded the directional derivatives at the origin.  One question: since we want 2 lambda ||b||_2 < c, don't we want lambda < c/(2||b||_2) instead of lambda < c||b||_2/2?